# Can I reference a timer by its Tag in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

For a project of mine, I have many timers which all control the fading of a media player, each timer has a name of `Fade_` and then a unique index number starting from `0`, i.e. `Fade_0`, `Fade_1`, `Fade_2` e.t.c.

I want to find an easy way of being able to reference these timers so that I can start them, however, I cannot find an easy way to do this.

I have tried the following, but timers are not classed as controls and so this doesn't work.

```
Dim MyFadeTimer As Timer = Controls.Find("Fade_" & KeyIndex, True)(0)
MyFadeTimer.Enabled = True
```

How can I achieve a similar thing?

EDIT: By using a global list pf `Dim FadeTimers As New List(Of Timer)` I can reference them, but when populating the list using `Dim FadeTimers As New List(Of Timer)({Fade_0, Fade_1, Fade_2...})` I get an error saying that there is nothing in the list when I call it using `FadeTimers(KeyIndex).start()`. However, when I populate the list using `FadeTimers.AddRange({Fade_0, Fade_1, ...}) it works?

Why does the first method of populating the list not work but the second does?

Comment: How do you reference them in principle if they are not controls?

Comment: You can't achieve a similar thing because there's no similar collection that `Timers` are added to. If you want a collection containing your `Timers` then you need to create one. You can then get one by index, `Tag` or you can use a `Dictionary`. That said, how many `Timers` do you think you need? Most times that I've seen people use multiple, they actually only need one. There's no reason that you can't have one `Tick` multiple times after different intervals.

Comment: @jmcilhinney My project is a virtual piano, and I need to use a timer to fade the sound out after a key is released. Because on my piano you can press more than one key at a time, I need to have a timer for each key.

Comment: @GSerg I'm confused what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, you must use AddRange().  Order matters, the list initialization runs too early.  Before the constructor could complete the InitializeComponent() method call.  So the variables are still Nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant where would I have to initialize the list to not have to use AddRange?

Comment: SOLVED: To not have to use AddRange I just had to not have the list as a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add them all manually to a `List(Of Timer)`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private KeyIndex As Integer
    Private Timers As New List(Of Timer)({Fade_0, Fade_1, Fade_2, Fade_3, Fade_4})

    Private Sub Foo()
        Timers(KeyIndex).Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

A variation would be to populate the List from the Load() event:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private KeyIndex As Integer
    Private FadeTimers As New List(Of Timer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FadeTimers.AddRange({Fade_0, Fade_1, ...}) 
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you don't want to list them all out, then you can use Reflection to find them.  Note that we have to add an underscore "_" before the Timer name.  This is being done only once, when the Form loads:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private KeyIndex As Integer
    Private Timers As New List(Of Timer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo
        Dim flags As Reflection.BindingFlags = Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4 ' <-- Change the 4 to the highest number of your Timers
            fi = Me.GetType.GetField("_Fade_" & i, flags)
            If Not IsNothing(fi) Then
                Timers.Add(fi.GetValue(Me))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you can access the timers by index just like in the first example:

```
Timers(KeyIndex).Start()
```

Comment: Hi I tried the first method you suggested, but I am now getting an error message when I call the .Start(): "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.this[int].get returned Nothing." and I don't know why? I did exactly as you said and made a new list of timers.

Comment: Update your post above with your new code and we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Curiously, if I populate the list using `.AddRange` then it works, but not with the `Private Timers As New List(Of Timer)({Fade_0, Fade_1, Fade_2, Fade_3, Fade_4})`

Comment: I'm not sure why the first syntax didn't work for you.  It worked fine for me in my testing.  I populated it and pulled a timer out by an index value and activated it.

Comment: I figured it out, in order to not use `.AddRange` I just needed to not have the list as a global variable, that seemed to work for me